# XSLT : Converting int to float / double value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file. How can I convert an int value to a double or float or vice versa using xslt? For example, assume the following 
source document :

```
<a>
  <b> 22 </b>
<a>
```

Result document

```
<a>
  <b> 22.0 </b>
<a>
```

Comment: That's backwards from your title.  Your source and result imply conversion from int to float. Which is it? Also, please show the XSLT you have written so far.

Comment: I said (or vice versa)! i want to learn a general form for converting a data type to any data type if it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [format-number()](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_formatnumber.asp) function.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="b">
    <b>
      <xsl:value-of select="format-number(., '#.0')" />
    </b>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks dear Tamas. what's about the float to int? (2.0-->2)

Comment: I find he related pattern <xsl:value-of select='format-number(2.0, "#")' />